# Find all levels of Children and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have input say

```
PARENT~CHILD
P1~C1
C1~C2
C2~C3
C3~C4
P2~C5
C5~C6
C6~C3
```

Now I need to find all levels of child and add to `MAP`. Something like below

```
P1={C1,C2,C3,C4}
P2={C5,C6,C3,C4}
```

I have tried below code where i'm manually adding the children for its top level parent. This takes so much time when the data is more. I'm new to Java and I dont know how to do this efficiently. I'm sure there will be some easy way to do this.

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map= new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("C1");
list.add("C2");
list.add("C3");
list.add("C4")

map.put("P1",list);
```

Comment: Since `C3` has child `C4`, wouldn't the result be `P2={C5,C6,C3,C4}`? If not, why not? How would you know that `C3~C4` doesn't apply to the `P2` descendant tree?

Comment: You are right. @Andreas. `P2` should have `C4` also. I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: How are parent-child stored? In a map?

Comment: @vivek_23. You mean the input? The input is coming from text file. I have to read it from text file and we can keep either in map or other way if it is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go with DFS & BFS algorithm while choosing algorithm is better for performance. Here is a naive method to solve such problem. It may help you.

**Model Class for relation Parent Child**

```
    class Relation {
        String parent;
        String child;

        // constructor
        public Relation(String parent, String child) {
            super();
            this.parent = parent;
            this.child = child;
        }

       // setter getter toString methods

    }
```

**Actual implementation**

```
    public static Map<String, List<String>> getAllLevelOfChildren(List<Relation> relations){
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> tempList = null;
        Set<String> parents = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> children = new HashSet<String>();
        
        for(Relation relation:relations){
            parents.add(relation.getParent());
            children.add(relation.getChild());
        }       
        parents.removeAll(children);        
        
        for(String key:parents){
            tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(key, tempList);
        }
       // Relation between Parent Child
        for(Relation rel : relations){              
            if(parents.contains(rel.getParent())){
                tempList = map.get(rel.getParent());
                tempList.add(rel.getChild());
                map.put(rel.getParent(), tempList);
            }               
            for(String parent:parents){
                tempList = map.get(parent);
                if(tempList.contains(rel.getParent())){
                    tempList.add(rel.getChild());
                    map.put(parent, tempList);
                }
            }
        }

        // Relation between children
        for (Relation rel : relations) {
            for (String parent : parents) {
                tempList = map.get(parent);
                if (tempList.contains(rel.getParent()) && !tempList.contains(rel.getChild())) {
                    tempList.add(rel.getChild());
                    map.put(parent, tempList);
                }
            }       
        }
        
        return map;
    }
```

**Main Method for test:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("P1~C1","C1~C2","C2~C3","C3~C4","P2~C5","C5~C6","C6~C3");
        System.out.println("Input List : "+list);
        List<Relation> relations = list.stream().map(o->{
            return new Relation(o.split("~")[0],o.split("~")[1]);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println("All level of Children : "+getAllLevelOfChildren(relations));    
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Input List : [P1~C1, C1~C2, C2~C3, C3~C4, P2~C5, C5~C6, C6~C3]
All level of Children : {P1=[C1, C2, C3, C4], P2=[C5, C6, C3, C4]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I will test all the cases and accept this.

Comment: There is one issue in this code. It is working only until 3 levels of subchild. It is not considering the later childs. How to correct it? Please suggest @Jimmy

Comment: @Avinash As per this code the level (>2) is depend on the last loop e.i Relation between children. If you repeat this loop once again the level will be increased to 4. Definitely general solution would be best choice..  Try to find the level from inputs and repeat it as per the level

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the data into a `Map<String, List<String>>` of parent node to list of direct child nodes, since a parent can presumably have multiple children.
2. Identify all the nodes without parents, which will be your "root parent" keys in the result map.
3. Using DFS ([Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) or BFS ([Breath First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)), collect all the descendants of each root parent.
   You might want to make the result a `Map<String, Set<String>>` to eliminate issues with merging/looping branches, unless that's guaranteed to not be possible.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the Answer. I'm really a beginner in Java. Not sure how to use DFS or BFS. Can you pls provide basic java code related to this? In the wikepedia Link, i couldn't get any code to implement the same. I know this might be very basic but i'm helpless :(

Comment: @Avinash Both articles include pseudocode, you just have to write that as Java code.